# Is the tilted mass function of Bernoulli a Bernoulli mass function?

Tags: statistics, monte-carlo

> Consider the Bernoulli probability mass function $$f(x) = p^x (1 - p)^{1-x}; x = 0,1$$
>   Find the corresponding tilted mass function $f_t(x)$. Is the tilted mass function a Bernoulli mass function?

Attempted solution - From my understanding the tilted mass function is the moment generating function. So, the tilted mass function is given by
\begin{align*}
f_t(x) = \mathbb{E}[e^{tx}] &= \sum_{x} e^{tx}f(x)\\
&= e^{t(0)}f(0) + e^{t(1)}f(1)\\
&= (1-p) + e^{t}p\\
&= 1 - p + e^{t}p
\end{align*}

Attempted solution part 2 - The tilted density of $f$ is given by $$f_t(x) = \frac{e^{tx}f(x)}{M(t)}$$ where $M(t)$ is the moment generating function. In our case the moment generating function of the Bernoulli probability mass function is $$M(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{tx}] = \sum_{x} e^{tx}f(x) = 1 - p +e^{t}p$$
Thus we have $$f_t(x) = \frac{e^{tx}p^{x}(1-p)^{1-x} }{1-p + e^{t}}$$
How do I check to see if this tilted mass function is a Bernoulli mass function? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write everything as an exponential family, your life will be easier.

The Bernoulli's original mass function is
\begin{align}
f(x) &\propto \exp\left(
x \log\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)
\right)
\end{align}

The tilted version has mass function:
\begin{align}
f_t(x) &\propto \exp(tx) f(x) \\
&= \exp\left(
x \left(\log\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right) + t\right)
\right),
\end{align}
which is clearly still Bernoulli.  It has natural parameter $\ell \triangleq \log\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right) + t$, which corresponds to probability
$$\frac{e^\ell}{1+e^\ell}.
$$

---

Your original mass function is

\begin{align}
f(x) &= p^x (1-p)^{1-x} \\
&\propto p^x (1-p)^{-x} \\
&= e^{x \log p - x \log(1-p)} \\
&= e^{x \log\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)}
\end{align}

Comment: So did I not find the tilted mass function from the given Bernoulli mass function given above?

Comment: @Wolfgang-1 your equation doesn't even look like a mass function since it doesn't depend on $x$.  Something's wrong with your definition of tilting.

Comment: Ok, I am just confused then how we find the tilted mass function given the Benoulli probability mass function $$f(x) = p^{x}(1-p)^{1-x};x = 0,1$$ I cant really follow what you have done and apply it to my case.

Comment: @Wolfgang-1  I did apply it to your case.  The definition that I know is $f(x)$-tilted by $t$ is proportional to $f(x)$ times $e^{tx}$.

Comment: But you use "original mass function" that seems to be defined differently to the what I have. Which is why I am still confused.

Comment: @Wolfgang-1 Did you try to rearrange your original mass function to get what I have?

Comment: I am not so sure I can, since you go from your original mass function to defining the tiled mass version where you state $f_t(x)$ which I am not sure is exactly. Could you just re-edit your answer to include more details and apply it to my mass function so that I understand.

Comment: @Wolfgang-1 does it make sense now?

Comment: So you took my probability mass function turned it into the so called original mass function? Now, I apply what you did to find the tilted version?

Comment: I just turned it into an unnormalized mass function $f(x) \propto …$ since when you do the tilt you're going to renormalize anyway, so what's the point of keeping track of normalization constants?  Then I did the tilting.

Comment: To be honest I do not understand what you are doing, the way you wrote the original mass function for my case is strange you have $f(x) = p^{x}(1-p)^{1-x}\alpha...$ why is $\alpha$ on the bottom

Comment: @Wolfgang-1 $\alpha$?  It's the proportionality relationship: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics)

Comment: Ok so you defined it as $f(x) = p^{x}(1-p)^{1-x}\alpha p^{x}(1-p)^{-x}$? The way it is written is a little confusing in your answer

Comment: you should put it on one single line, not two

Comment: Also, I edited my question since I cannot follow what you are doing, I believe I found the tilted mass function now

Comment: @Wolfgang-1 your normalizer is wrong because when $t=0$, you don't recover your original equation.  The numerator is fine; it's what I showed in my answer.  And by the way, there's nothing wrong with showing proportion on a second line.  I think it's easier to read that way.

Comment: The denominator should be the moment generating function correct?

Comment: If my numerator is ok, then is it my denominator that is wrong?

Comment: @Wolfgang-1 right (I think) and right.